# Fabric/crashlytics crash not showing up in main list, but listed

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

We are using Fabric/Crashlytics in our iOS app. Generally, our installation seems to be working well, with crashes from debug builds reporting, but we seem to have some odd problems with AdHoc builds.

- I cause an exception to occur in the code.
- exit the app, restart it.
- Go to Fabric dashboard.
- If I go to current release (56), I can see the crash I caused noted as '1 crashes' in the screen:
  [Fabric knows about the crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyhIS.png)
- Now, if I click the link for 'All issues for 1.0 (56)', it shows me no crashes:
  [But it is not available to view or select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyhIS.png)
- I have tried waiting a day for these to show up, and they do not. And, I have seen crashes on other devices not showing up as well.
- When I caused this crash, Fabric correctly noted that the DSYMs for this build were missing (ADhoc build), so I found them from the archived, zipped them, and uploaded them. That warning went away.
- But, the crash is not reported in the main list.
  [DSYMs are loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyhIS.png)
- I have reviewed various posts with other people having problems with Crashlytics. I have made sure the Fabric initialization is correct, and after other packages (like Dacebook and Twitter):

  ```
  [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
  ```
- The build scripts for debug and release are set to DWARF with dsyms.
- We have the Fabric run script with our API key in the XCode run script for our target.

Comment: It appears the links for the images did not upload properly. They all link to the same image.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you try re-uploading the dSYM once more and let me know if the crash shows up after?

Comment: @MikeBonnell I have this same issue where I have crashes listed on my main dashboard (app needs investigation) but going to the build number, there are no crashes listed. All DSYMs are loaded. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, this can happen if a crash has occurred, but the user hasn't relaunched the app to send the report.